# Angular Code coverage is report is marking comments aswell

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

When i generate code coverage report for my Angular code, it marks few lines that are not appropriate (comments and variable names etc...) as not covered. Due to which i am not able to reach 80% of code coverage which project expects at the end of our sprint.

Please refer to attached screenshot...

[code_coverage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYifI.png)

[code_coverage_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z05Hq.png)

Tried many things, by changing names and removing comments. but still it marks the same statement.

Comment: My coverage is over 90% and the comments and import statement are not being included in uncovered code

Comment: this is what we are not able to figure out. no idea why comments, variable names and even data types are highlighted as not covered.